# Font directory issues

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, materialize

Im having issues trying to get all my fonts to work after I grunt build. When I "grunt serve" my app fonts works fine.

The issue is some of my bower components css files use a different directory for fonts than what is expected for grunt.

Grunt wants fonts in `app/styles/fonts/` if they are to be copied during the build

I have a custom font placed in `app/font` (i can change this in my main css so not a big issue)

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'iec_unicoderegular';
src: url('../font/Unicode_IEC_symbol/Unicode_IEC_symbol.eot');
src: url('../font/Unicode_IEC_symbol/Unicode_IEC_symbol.eot?#iefix')
```

materialize.css wants fonts in `../font/roboto/` and `../font/material-design-icons`

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Roboto";
src: url("../font/roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff2") format("woff2"), 

@font-face {
font-family: "Material-Design-Icons";
src: url("../font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
```

materialdesignicons.css wants fonts in `../fonts/`

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MaterialDesignIcons';
src: url("../fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.eot?v=1.0.62");
```

I do not want to change the css in the bower components rather is there a change in my gruntfile.js that could take all the font sources and combine them then to one font file and modify the css during the build to reflect the changes? If not what is the best way to handle this issue? My gruntfile.js is unmodified. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means an expert. I found your question after hitting the same problem. I'll include all the steps here for completeness.

I installed the `roboto-fontface` package with bower:

```
bower install roboto-local --save
```

Then I ran

```
grunt build
```

This ensures the roboto-fontface css file is injected into my index.html file:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/roboto-fontface/roboto-fontface.css" />`

and it also updates the `dist` directory so I can see the roboto font in action.

Unfortunately the fonts were not copied to my `dist` directory. Note, I did have a fonts directory ,but this was for bootstrap fonts. My dist directory looked like this:

```
   |-fonts
   |-images
   |-scripts
   |-styles
```

The `roboto-fontface` CSS file was looking in `dist/styles/fonts/` for the fonts:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('fonts/Roboto-Thin.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Roboto-Thin.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/Roboto-Thin.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/Roboto-Thin.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/Roboto-Thin.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I decided the best thing was just to put the fonts there and not modify any css files. I modified the `copy dist` rule in `Gruntfile.js` adding:

```
{
expand: true,
cwd: 'bower_components/roboto-fontface/',
src: 'fonts/*',
dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/'
}
```

This copies everything inside the roboto-fontface `bower_components/roboto-fontface/fonts` directory to a font **sub-directory** of styles.

My new, and working, dist directory looks like (note the `font` sub-directory of `styles`)

```
  |-fonts
  |-images
  |-scripts
  |-styles
  |---fonts
```

I wasn't sure where exactly to modify the copy-dist rule, so for completeness, here's my new rule in its entirety:

```
// Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
copy: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      dot: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      src: [
        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
        '.htaccess',
        '*.html',
        'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
        'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
      ]
    }, {
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/images',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
      src: ['generated/*']
    }, {
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
      src: 'fonts/*',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    },
    **{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'bower_components/roboto-fontface/',
      src: 'fonts/*',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/'
    }**]
  },
  styles: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    dest: '.tmp/styles/',
    src: '{,*/}*.css'
  }
},
```